# Java: Singleton en la misma clase

Tags: java

Tengo una duda acerca de que sí es posible crear un `Singleton` en una clase donde yo tengo getters, setters y el `Singleton` lo quiero crear en el constructor, sí es posible podrían ponerme un ejemplo por favor. Gracias

```
public class CheckIn{

  private int folio;
  private String customer;
  private String delivered;
  private ArrayList<Bitmap> images;

  public CheckIn(int folio, String customer, String delivered){
    this.folio = folio;
    this.customer = customer;
    this.delivered = delivered;
    //AQUI QUIERO IMPLEMENTAR EL SINGLETON
  }

  public int getFolio() {
    return folio;
  }

  public void setFolio(int folio) {
    this.folio = folio;
  }

  public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  public String getDelivered() {
    return delivered;
  }

  public void setDelivered(String delivered) {
    this.delivered = delivered;
  }

  public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages() {
    return images;
  }

  public void setImages(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray) {
    this.images = bitmapArray;
  }

}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta también es un poco confusa respecto a que quieres crear el singleton en el constructor. Te refieres a instanciarlo o a crear la lógica para ello?

Comment: A mí sí me quedó claro: quiere saber si se puede implementar el patrón singleton en el constructor.

Comment: Agregue mi codigo para tener mas claridad

Comment: Por cierto solo estoy checando, no estoy seguro que se pueda por eso pregunto, de lo contrario que no se pueda creare mi singleton el clase independiente

Comment: Luego de tu edición, aún no me queda claro que es lo que persigues. Te recomiendo explicar para qué quieres crear un singleton, y si lo que quieres es que la clase CheckIn sea el singleton o si quieres referenciar allí un singleton de otra clase.

Comment: @jachguate tiene razón, tu código sólo es un placeholder de datos y no tendría mucho sentido que hicieras un singleton de esa clase

Comment: Cómo se llama que quieres hacer Singleton? Es esa misma?

Comment: Hola @Javierfr al ver tu clase me parece que es un Objeto, creo que no debería aplicar crear un Singleton en este caso, ya que regularmente creas varias instancias de un objeto de este tipo, agrego una respuesta donde comento sobre esto y la implementación del singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Un Singleton necesita un método estatico para instarlo, para asegurarse que solamente hay una instancia. El modificador `static` aun no esta permitido dentro de métodos de miembros o sus constructores. Así lo que puedes hacer es declarar el Singleton como clase propia, pero instarlo en el constructor.

```
public class Singleton {
    // campo estatico para recibir la unica instancia del Singleton
    private static final Singleton s = null;

    private Singleton() {
        // lo que necesites de código
    }

    public synchronized static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (s==null) s = new Singleton(); // instar el Singleton si no hay todavía
        return s;
    }
}
```

Y en tu constructor:

```
public CheckIn(int folio, String customer, String delivered){
    this.folio = folio;
    this.customer = customer;
    this.delivered = delivered;
    //AQUI QUIERO IMPLEMENTAR EL SINGLETON
    Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    // El constructor privado no permite que se genere un constructor por defecto.
    // (con mismo modificador de acceso que la definición de la clase) 
    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: un poco de explicación de lo que hace tu código ayudaría mucho al usuario para entender el fondo del problema y no sólo cómo se hace :)

Comment: Si explicaras que haces en cada proceso aprenderiamos mas, Gracias abrahamhs

Comment: Está es una forma de crear el patrón Singleton, pero no como lo pide el usuario, es explícito en la pregunta que él desea la implementación del patrón dentro del constructor.