# Inyectar objetos en Java

Tags: java, java-ee, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con Java EE en donde se pueden inyectar objectos simplemente con la anotación @Inject sin embargo no sé como hacerlo sin usar Java ee.

Lo que quiero es que el mismo objeto con la misma instancia se pueda usar en clases diferentes, por ejemplo para las siguientes clases :

```
public class Main {

Foo foo;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    foo.setMensaje("hola");

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.imprimirFoo();
}

}
```

Bar :

```
public class Bar {

private Foo foo;

public void imprimirFoo(){
    System.out.println(foo.getMensaje());
}

}
```

Foo:

```
public class Foo {
private String mensaje;

public String getMensaje() {
    return mensaje;
}

public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
}

}
```

Quisiera que me imprimiera dos veces hola, pero no sé como hacerlo sin usar la anotación @Inject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes implementar un patrón de diseño llamado Singleton.

Recordar  que JEE son un conjunto de servicios y en los servicios que proporciona ya existen clases que implementan una gran cantidad de patrones de diseño.

Si aún asi no encuentras la solución que necesitas implementala

[ver el siguiente link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36973/java-singleton-en-la-misma-clase/36978)

Answer (score 1):

Primero te felicito por querer ir más allá de la utilización de los productos. Si continuas así pronto podrás dominar cualquier lenguaje y cualquier framework fácilmente.

La firma @inject es relativa al patrón de inyección de dependencias. Te dejo algunos links [Wiki español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_dependencias) [Descripción del creador del patrón (Martin Fowler)](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection).

Todo esto es parte de las técnicas más modernas de la programación orientada a  objeto. La inyección de dependencias es muy similar en funcionamiento al patrón de diseño Strategy, bueno, y de el set inicial de patrones de diseño [Puedes encontrar el libro acá](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612) nace todo lo que hoy conocemos como Frameworks, Arquitecturas empresariales, etc. Puedes ver una descripción más amigable [acá](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) en inglés y en distintos lenguajes de programación.

Espero te sirva.